# Add Google Play service to an Android library project in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, library-project

I have a library project FooLib which uses Google play service (location service). When I was using Eclipse, I have google-play-services-lib (also as a library project) in my workspace and I include it in FooLib, and everything is working fine. Now I am migrating to Android studio and I could not figure out a way to include Google play service in a library project. Here is what I have done so far:

1. Installed Google player service, Google Repository in the SDK manager. (I am using the latest Android studio 1.0.1)

[image]
2. Added compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+' to the build.gradle file for FooLib under dependencies. Sync the gradle file. Here is my guild.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {  
    compileSdkVersion 21  
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {  
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'  
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.5.0-core.jar')  
}
```

3. The official doc (http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) mentioned that I also need to add

   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
              android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

to the manifest as a child of <application> tag. But in the manifest file for a library project, there is no <application> tag. I tried without the meta-data tag or adding a dummy <application> tag in the manifest and attached meta-data tag to it. Neither case works.

I tried both AndroidManifest files below
[image]
Or
[image]

I am still getting
[image]

Does anybody know how to add Google play service to a library project in Android studio? Much appreciated!

Comment: Just add project as module and give ref as lib in Studio with ref of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Comment: Thanks, Parag. FooLib is added in Android Studio as a module. That part is fine but it needs google play service as one of the dependencies, which I could not figure out how.

Comment: You can also add dependencies to module

Comment: Yes, that's what I did by adding compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+' to the dependencies list. But for some reason, the compiler just won't recognize it. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Just now i cross checked with my project , m able to run

Comment: gradle showing any error  ?

Comment: I just added some screen shots to the post. Is it possible that you can share your project with me so I can compare with my configuration to see where the problem might be? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, accidentally clicked chat

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this?